# remove suffix with pattern in R dataframe

Tags: r

I have an R dataframe with column names as following,

```
MMR42_L_2_S52_L001_R1_001
MMR42_LN_2_S51_L001_R1_001
MMR43_N_1_S53_L001_R1_001
MMR48_N_1_S54_L001_R1_001
MMR612_S55_L001_R1_001
MMR658_S56_L001_R1_001
```

I have to remove the _S* from each column name

Desired Column names:

```
MMR42_L_2
MMR42_LN_2
MMR43_N_1
MMR48_N_1
MMR612
MMR658
```

My Idea

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  rename_all(.funs = funs(sub("\\_S*", "", names(df1)))) %>%
```

I could not get the desired result with the above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within the `rename_at/_all`, the `.` is the column name.  We don't need `names(.)`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df1 %>%
    rename_all(~ str_remove(., "\\_S.*"))
```

Or using the OP's code

```
df1 %>%
   rename_all(.funs = funs(sub("\\_S.*", "", .)))
```

Comment: second suggestion removes _S from column names but does not remove string after _S

Comment: @Khaned sorry, a typo, it should be `\\_S.*` instead of `\\S*`

Comment: 2nd works but 1st suggestion gives Error in str_remove(., "\\_S.*") : could not find function "str_remove"

Comment: @Khaned Have you uploaded `library(stringr)` What is the `packageVersion('stringr')` may be you have an older version of 'stringr

Comment: Now it works, I installed ‘1.4.0’ version stringr package. Thanks